# How to interpret the axis of distribution

Tags: probability-distributions, normal-distribution

Say, we have a normal distribution $f(x) \sim N(\mu,\sigma^2)$, and we have the graph of this distribution.

What is the vertical and horizontal axis meaning here?

How does this graph derive from the graph of histogram?

Comment: What meaning are you looking for?

Comment: Horizontal axis is just values of the variable. The vertical axis is a bit more subtle, as it is not quite probability but more "probability per unit on the horizontal axis".

Comment: As for your histogram question: if you have a histogram with bins of width $\Delta x$ comprising $N$ total data points, then dividing the $y$ coordinates of this histogram by $N \Delta x$ gives you an approximation of the probability density function. This works because it makes the total area of all of the rectangles equal to $1$, whereas previously it was $N \Delta x$.

Comment: @lan When I reading something, it says, x has a normal distribution conditioned on t. x should be a function of t. So what is the horizontal variable here?

Comment: @GehuaZhang It's not really a function of $t$. Its distribution is a function of $t$. But for each fixed $t$, that distribution is understood the same way, so that the horizontal axis is again just values of the variable $X$.